# AngularJS Does not send HTTP Post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code:

```
application.controller('userLoginController', function($scope,$http){
window.document.title = "User Login";
$scope.form = { username: '',password: ''};
$scope.submitLogin = function(){
    var config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'server_app/login.php',
        data: {
            'username' : $scope.form.password,
            'password' : $scope.form.password

        }
    };
    var request = $http(config);
    request.then(function (response){
        $scope.errorMessage = response.data;
    },function(error){
        $scope.errorMessage = error.data;
        })
    }
});
```

I was trying to send POST request to backend server which look like that:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

After submitting my data with a button I should get array with $_POST back.
Insteed of that I get

```
    array (size=0)
  empty
```

My HTML code look like that:

```
    <input placeholder="Login" class="searchProduct" autocomplete="off" name="username"  type="text" ng-model="form.username"><br>
<input placeholder="Password" class="searchProduct" autocomplete="off" type="password" name="password" ng-model="form.password"/>
<div class="button" ng-click="submitLogin();">Login</div>
```

I don't see any problem here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are receiving data as below in php file as angular code seems to be fine .

$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

Comment: Indeed thank you, But I don't get one thing why do I need to write it like that? Using Jquery for example only thing I'm doing is var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: when you sent form data with formet enctype=”multipart/form-data” then you can receive it with $_POST , since you are sending data as json you need to use file_get_contents('php://input') .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: Thank you , but it still does not answer my question, I want to know why it's not working.